# Powershell replace content in file adds redundent carriage return

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that should be running from a cmd script:

```
powershell -command "(Get-Content %baseKitPathFile%) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'Latest', '%version%' } | Set-Content %baseKitPathFile%"
```

The script is working fine and replacing the content of `Latest` to a `version` variable however it also adds carriage return after the end of the file

How can I search replace a text file content without the extra carriage return

maybe be trying to use `[io.file]:`

The most important is that if should be running from cmd script

Comment: Replace `Set-Content` with `Out-File`

Comment: not working, still adding extra line

Answer (score 0):

`Set-Content` and `Out-File` both put a linebreak after each line, including the last one. To avoid that you must use an `IO.File` method:

```
powershell -Command "$txt = (Get-Content %baseKitPathFile%) -replace 'Latest', '%version%'; [IO.File]::WriteAllText('%baseKitPathFile%', $txt)"
```

A PowerShell script would be better to handle than the above commandline, though:

```psh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter()][string]$Filename,
  [Parameter()][string]$Version
)

$txt = (Get-Content $Filename) -replace 'Latest', $Version
[IO.File]::WriteAllText($Filename, $txt)
```

Call it like this:

```
powershell -File "C:\path\to\your.ps1" "%baseKitPathFile%" "%version%"
```

Comment: The only drawback to this method is that .NET paths and PowerShell paths are often different. For example, while you can pass "~\somefile.txt" to `Set-Content` or `Out-File`, .NET will not understand it. Same with paths based on the current directory or those mapped to PSDrives. To work around this, first resolve the path with `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($Filename)`.